# Constant drawing in drawRect?

Tags: uiview, drawrect, cgcontext

Hey guys i have another problem.
I'm using a custom UIView class with the method drawRect.

No i have build a design in PaintCode and i call the method for drawing it in a drawRect method. The problem i have is that the drawRect only get's called once.

The thing i made in paintcode looks like a speedometer and the value of changes so i need to redraw it every time.

I have no idea on how to do this?

I have tried to use:

```
[PCView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

But that doesn't seem to work for me.
Can you guys help me out, big thanks.

Comment: First off, you should follow apple's naming convention, which is lowercase initial for objects: `pcView`. Second of all, make sure your `PCView` object is not nil, and that line of code gets executed.

Comment: Also, this question has nothing to do with Xcode. I've fixed your tags and title to remove it.